# Error: Unhandled exception maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple code: when a checkbox is checked show an alert otherwise show another alert.

```
function test() {
  if (this.view.checkBoxAgree.onSelection() === true) {
    alert("okay");
  } else {
    alert("cancel");
  }
}
```

But, I got an error:

> Unhandled exception maximum call stack size exceeded.

I guess this is related to Eea6, but I don't know too much about es6.

Comment: Without the HTML, it is hard to know what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using an event `onSelection` and this is creating a cycle which is eventually overflowing the stack. Instead, you should use a property like `checked`. Post your HTML code so we can help you because we have no idea about the `this.view.checkBoxAgree`. Here is how you do it with standard form and checkbox in a hierarchy similar to yours:

```js
function test() {
  if (this.view.checkBoxAgree.checked === true) {
    alert("okay");
  } else {
    alert("cancel");
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="view">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxAgree" onclick="test();" /> Agree
</form>
```

Alternatively, you can wire the event in JavaScript instead of HTML and access the checkbox directly using `this` like this:

```js
document.getElementById("checkBoxAgree").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.checked === true) {
    alert("okay");
  } else {
    alert("cancel");
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="view">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxAgree" /> Agree
</form>
```